# A link to the text file downloads it rather than opening it in browser

Tags: browser, httprequest

In my webpage I have a link to a text file something like this.

```
    <a href="">Link</a>
```

When I click on the link the browser downloads the file rather than opening it in the browser.

can anyone tell me how I can do this. Is there any browser changes I need to make..? The link actually is a direct link to the text file itself, and not redirecting the request from a different page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show what href="" contains.

Comment: <a href=\""+getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/LOG_FILES/log_base_instal_"+domain+".txt\">Link</a> domain is just a random String

Answer (score 0):

check the HTTP headers that are being used to serve the file, you many need to
fix the server so that it uses the correct mime-type and disposition when serving the file.

If the browser doesn't recognise the type or sees "Disposition: Attachment" it will save the file.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat7.. can u tell me.. how can I set HTTP headers in server itself, so that for all .txt requests, the Headers are set to "Content-Disposition: attachment;"

Answer (score 0):

Either change your file to .html or change your webserver mime-type settings to display .txt files.